# REACT Js, prevState not saving the previous state in an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, setstate

I'm having a problem that I can't solve. I have an empty object saved in a useState, which I have to fill dynamically according to some filters to do a search in an API.
When I choose a filter it has no problems, it saves it for me. But when I choose a second filter, it deletes the previous one and saves the new filter. I am using: https://ant.design/components/table/

useState

```
const [savedFilters, setSavedFilters] = useState({})
```

onValuesChange

```
 <Form
            form={form}
            onValuesChange={e => setSavedFilters(
                prevState => ({...prevState, e })
            )}
>
```

If anyone could help me I would appreciate it!

Comment: Please read [Is English required on stack overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow/13684#13684)  (tl;dr: It is). Other language versions of SO are available. Note to other SO users: [Do not translate this on behalf of the OP, if they can't ask the question in English, then they will struggle to respond to comments and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/19068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to spread 'e' ?

```
   onValuesChange={e => setSavedFilters(
                prevState => ({...prevState, ...e })
            )}
```

I would be nice if you told us what value is in `savedFilters` after update